The well-ordering number of second-order logic
The definitions and referred pages are from (Model-Theoretic Logics, Barwise 1985), primarily from chapter II. A free version is available here: Chapter II
Definition (pinning down ordinals): Let < $\in$ $\tau$  and $\Phi$ $\subseteq$ $\mathscr L$[$\tau$] for  $\mathscr L$[$\tau$] is the class of all $\mathscr L$-sentences of vocabulary $\tau$. We say that $\Phi$ 'pins down' the ordinal $\alpha$ via <, if
i) For all $\mathfrak U$ $\models$ $\Phi$, <$^\mathfrak U$ is a well-ordering of its field/domain
ii)There is a model $\mathfrak U$ of $\Phi$ such that <$^\mathfrak U$ is a well-ordering of order type  $\alpha$
(Page 60)
Definition (Well-ordering number): We define w$_\kappa$($\mathscr L$) to be the supremum of all ordinals that can be pinned down by a set of $\mathscr L$-sentences $\Phi$ of power (cardinality of $\Phi$) $\le$ $\kappa$. The well-ordering number of a logic can be be defined as the supremum of all ordinals pinned down by an arbitrary set of L-sentences. If there exists no such ordinal than w($\mathscr L$) = $\infty$ (arbitrarily large ordinals are pinned down), this is equivalent to characterizing the class of well-orderings (Page 61).
This is effectively the limit of order types of well-ordering that can be defined by a logic and has ties to compactness and Löwenheim–Skolem properties. I.e, the well-ordering number of first order logic is $\omega$, meaning it can only define finite well-orderings.
Definition (bounded): A logic is bounded  if there is no single sentence that pins down arbitrarily large ordinals. Logics which have a notion of well-ordering, I.e., second-order logic $\mathscr L$$^2$ are unbounded (or called 'strong' in other papers I have seen). Thus, the 'bound' of a logic is the supremum of all ordinals that can be pinned down by an arbitrary $\phi$ $\in$ $\mathscr L$[$\tau$] (Page 61).
It can be observed that every unbounded logic has a well-ordering number of $\infty$ (this relation does not necessarily hold the other way, consider the infinitary logic $\mathscr L$$_\infty,$$_\omega$ which has well-ordering number of $\infty$ but is bounded).
Large well-ordering numbers come with large hanf numbers, via theorem 6.1.6 the upper bounds of hanf numbers can be determined via the well-ordering number
Theorem 6.1.6: Assume that each ordinal $\alpha$ < w$_\kappa$($\mathscr L$) can be pinned down by a set $\Psi$$_\alpha$ of sentences, |$\Psi$$_\alpha$| $\le$ $\kappa$, having a model $\mathfrak U$ of power < h$_\kappa$($\mathscr L$) where <$^\mathfrak U$ is of order type $\alpha$. Then for every $\lambda$ < h$_\kappa$($\mathscr L$), h$_\kappa$($\mathscr L$) $\ge$ $\beth$$_{w_\kappa}$$_($$_{\mathscr L)} ($$\lambda$). (Page 66)
Note: $\beth$$_{\alpha +1} ($$\kappa$) is defined (via recursion) as 2$^{\beth_\alpha} (\kappa)$ and $\beth$$_\beta$($\kappa$)= Sup{$\beth$$_\alpha$($\kappa$)|$\alpha$ < $\beta$} for $\beta$ is a limit ordinal.
As a consequence of this theorem (let w($\mathscr L$) = $\infty$) we get w($\mathscr L$) = $\infty$ $\iff$ h($\mathscr L$) = $\infty$
A famous result of Barwise is that the hanf number of second-order logic is greater than the least measurable cardinal (no upper bound has yet been determined). Using the generalization of theorem 6.1.6, if h($\mathscr L$) $\neq$ $\infty$ then w($\mathscr L$) $\neq$ $\infty$, so w($\mathscr L$$^2$) $\neq$ $\infty$. This seems to contradict the above since $\mathscr L$$^2$ is unbounded so it should have a well-ordering number of $\infty$. Can anyone experienced in model theory explain what exactly has caused this contradiction? Otherwise this would be proof that $\mathscr L$$^2$ has no hanf number (which I doubt is the case). I may have misunderstood the applications of the concepts of well-ordering numbers and bounded/unbounded logics, so clarification would also be appreciated.

I don't understand your argument that $wc=\infty$ implies $h(\mathscr{L})=\infty$. Indeed, SOL is a counterexample to that claim since every set-sized logic has a Hanf number $<\infty$. I think you might be mixing up $h(\mathscr{L})$ (which is just $h_1(\mathscr{L})$) and $\sup_{\kappa\in Ord}h_\kappa(\mathscr{L})$ in applying Theorem 6.1.6?

@NoahSchweber Yeah that might be it, there is an issue in the generalisation of the theorem. Is there any other issues with the implications of an unbounded logic? It does feel weird for second-order logic to have a well-ordering number of $\infty$ and have a hanf number < $\infty$

Special thanks to Noah Schweber and Edgar A. Valenzuela for explaining important model-theoretic concepts which helped me realize the answer.
First of all, as Noah Schweber has point out w($\mathscr{L}$) = $w_1(\mathscr{L}$). As $\mathscr{L}^2$ is unbounded due to capturing the notion of well-ordering (it can defined the entire class of WO), an implication of this is that w($\mathscr{L}^2$) = $w_1(\mathscr{L}^2$) = $\infty$. This is is equivalent to having no well-ordering number at all. Theorem 6.1.6 allows for the (upper bound of a) hanf number for a logic $\mathscr{L}$, h($\mathscr{L}$) to be calculated from the well-ordering number w($\mathscr{L}$) given that such a well-ordering number exists. Thus, theorem 6.1.6 cannot be applied to $\mathscr{L}^2$ since it has no well-ordering number and so there is no contradiction.
As Edgar has pointed out to me in our private conversations, "the well-ordering number ensures that hanf number, but not the other way around." That is $\exists$ w($\mathscr{L}$) $\implies$ $\exists$ h($\mathscr{L}$), but $\exists$ h($\mathscr{L}$) $\not \implies$ $\exists$ w($\mathscr{L}$). From this we can gather the following relation:
h($\mathscr{L}$) = $\infty$ $\implies$ w($\mathscr{L}$) = $\infty$, and
w($\mathscr{L}$) = $\infty$ $\not\implies$ h($\mathscr{L}$) = $\infty$
